# how a server written with node.js call google map's api?

Tags: node.js, google-maps

For example, I have lots of GPS data in server.(the server is written with node.js)
Can the server send a post(and the data) to google map to call its api and return data for 
the server?

I wish you can explain to me with an example(with some code is better！:) ）

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at the core [http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) module and the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module from mikael.

Comment: This link may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412946/how-to-block-after-http-request-with-node-js/14413430#14413430